# Understanding Implicit Differentiation (intuitive)

Tags: calculus, derivatives, implicit-differentiation

Let's say we have:

$$ x^2 +y^2 = 25 $$

definition of differentiation:
$$\lim_{x\to h} = \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}=\frac{dy}{dx}$$

when we do implicit differentiation we have:

$$ df(x^2 +y^2) =df(25) $$?

we are differentiating with respect to what? I need the intuition for implicit differentiation of what is going on with the geometry when we perform implicit differentiation.

is there any connection with partial differentiation?

Comment: where did your 3rd equation come from

Comment: @JobHunter69 I thought that was what is going on when we perform partial diff, we are using differential df

Comment: Look up the Implicit Function Theorem. It basically says that when we have a relation between $x$ and $y$ we can find a small neighborhood around a point in the relation where $y$ is a function of $x$ or $x$ is a function of $y$. This justifies the implicit derivative. Unfortunately, implicit differentiation is taught in a first calculus course but really can't be understood until later in your mathematics education.

Comment: @JohnDouma I would like to see an answer more in detail

Comment: Then look up the Implicit Function Theorem.

Comment: @JohnDouma but with your intuition

Comment: Have you ever hovered your mouse cursor over the upvote and downvote arrows? The text for the upvote arrow says "This questions shows research effort; it is useful and clear" while the text for the downvote arrow says "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful". Which category do you think this post falls under?

Comment: @JohnDouma let me edit the question

Comment: Hint: as others suggested, read up on the IFT.  Surely there are examples in your textbook assuming you are in a calculus class.  Try an even simpler example like $x=y^{3}$ and find $dy/dx$ *not* $dx/dy$ using the IFT. Think about what this is telling you - can you get results at particular points $(x,y)$ without a lot of algebra on the derivatives? Then try the algebra to see that you've gotten it right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a multivariable function you don't have, e.g. $f(x^2+y^2)$, but $f(x,y)$. $f(x^2+y^2)$ actually means $f(g(x,y))$ where $g$ is a multi-valued function and $f$ is a one variable function having the range of $g$ as its domain. (This effectively makes $f$ a   multi-variable function, too, but I seek to avoid the multivariable chain rule here, so lets ignore that for right now!).

---

Consider a circle. $x^2+y^2=R^2$.

Then $y=\pm \sqrt{R^2-x^2}$

$(x+\Delta x)^2+(y+\Delta y)^2=x^2+y^2+2x\Delta x+2y\Delta y=R^2+2x\Delta x + 2y\Delta y$

So

$[(x+\Delta x)+(y+\Delta y)^2]-(x^2+y^2)=2x\Delta x+ 2y \Delta y$

But we are constrained to the circle. $(x+\Delta x, y+\Delta y)$ is also a point on the circle, so

$(x+\Delta x)^2+(y+\Delta y)^2=R^2  $ as well.

But this can only happen if $2x\Delta x + 2y\Delta y=0\implies \frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}=\frac{-x}{y}$

Consider implicit differentiation:

$x^2+y^2=25$

$2x+2y\cdot y'=0$

$y'=\frac{-x}{y}$

---

Regular Differentiation:

$y=\pm \sqrt{R^2-x^2}$

$y'=\frac{-2x}{2\sqrt{R^2-x^2}}=\frac{-x}{\sqrt{R^2-x^2}}=\frac{-x}{y}$

---

Or basic geometry. A line tangent to a circle is perpendicular a radius joining the center of the circle to that point.

Line $y=mx$ passing through the origin will intersect a circle at $x^2+y^2=R^2$ or $x^2(1+m^2)=R^2\implies x^2=\frac{R^2}{1+m^2}$

Then $y^2=R^2-x^2\implies y^2= \frac{m^2R^2}{1+m^2}$

All this implies $m=y/x$ is the slope of the radius between the center and some point on the circle. The slope perpendicular to a line of slope $m$ is $-1/m$ which in this case is $-x/y$

These principles can be utilized in three dimensions where $z=x^2+y^2$ and the partial derivatives describe properties of related geometric objects as well. $z=x^2+y^2$ is a paraboloid. $z=25$ is a plane cutting it perpendicular to its axis of symmetry. So now you can also use tangent planes to discuss geometric properties of the paraboloid. Since you have two independent variables, you now have two slopes worry about at each point and if $z$ is a constant, those slopes tell you something about tangent lines within that plane.

For more rigor, try here : [Implicit Function Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_function_theorem)

---

What's going on here can be generalized.

Whether $x^2+y^2=25$ or $x^3\sin(xy)+e^{-2xy}=-45x$ is your function, you can set it up in the form $f(x,y)=0$.

So $x^2+y^2=25\implies x^2+y^2-25=0$

If you have $f(x,y)=0$, the total derivative is $df = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}dx + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}dy$

But since $f$ is a constant, i.e. 0, $df \equiv 0$.

$0\equiv \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}dx + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} dy \implies 
 \frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{-\partial f /\partial x}{\partial f/\partial y}$

If $f(x,y)=x^2+y^2-25$, then $\partial f/\partial x = 2x$ and $\partial f /\partial y =2y$.

So $\frac{dy}{dx} =\frac{-x}{y}$

---

So yes, very close connection with partial differentiation. Good call on that.

This isn't developed rigorously and misses some important details like how multivariable limits work, but is hopefully good enough for some intuition